# ASP.NET Web API ModelState do not contains all parameters, validation do not work

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I'm using ASP.NET Web API and I have this POST method in controller:

```
[Route("Order/{siteId}/{orderId}")]
public HttpResponseMessage Post(long siteId, long orderId, OrderInformation orderInfo)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid) { ... }
}
```

I have a couple data annotations in OrderInformation class (Required etc.) but unfortunately validation do not work. It is because ModelState do not contains key for orderInfo. It contains only siteId and orderId.

[image]

So my question is why orderInfo parameter is not included in ModelState. I have not idea why it works so weird because I use similar code on different places and it works fine.

Edit:

Here is model (OrderInformation class):

```
public class tOrderInformation
{

    [Required]
    public string LoyaltyNumber;
    [Required]
    public string SpecialInstructions;
    public bool SendEmail;

    ...
    // few more string properties, no data annotations
}
```

Edit 2:

I'm sending complex type in body serialized into JSON. I also tried this signature of method:

```
[Route("Order/{siteId}/{orderId}")]
public HttpResponseMessage Post(long siteId, long orderId, [FromBody] OrderInformation orderInfo)
```

Comment: To know why your model isn't passed back to an action, we need to see the model and, more importantly, the view, not the action.

Comment: @Coda17 I have added model class. It's Web API so no view

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Uff I just found what is the problem. There can't be public fields in model, it must be properties.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't pass complex object in the url. Get the orderinfo from the body of the request

```
[Route("Order/{siteId}/{orderId}")]
public HttpResponseMessage Post(long siteId, long orderId, [FromBody]OrderInformation orderInfo)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid) { ... }
}
```

And send the object using json. This way it shouldn't be null.

Comment: Thanks for response. I do it in this way. I'm sending JSON data in body of request. I also tried both options with and without FromBody attribute but neither one work.

Comment: Ok it is common then. If you are sending from the body make sure that you keep the [FromBody] tag and 95% of the time when it's null it's the Json syntax so check if you are sending the object correctly. Fiddle around with the json object. Tip : you can easily test request using this free tool : https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/advanced-rest-client/hgmloofddffdnphfgcellkdfbfbjeloo

Comment: Also try to keep you dto(model) as simple as possible. Remove the [Required] tags. Narrow it down to it's simplest form and see if you can get it working this way.